# Site broken IE11 in windows 8 - goes to Enterprise mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

Our site is breaking real bad in IE11. What's happening is that it goes into "Document Mode" 5 (Default) and Browser profile is forced as Enterprise.

As soon as I change Enterprise to Desktop, the site is all good.

Is there any way, I can force my site not to go to Enterprise  and/or Use Edge as document mode ?

I have tried following but nothing worked:-

putting this right after

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

changing Doctype as :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
```

and

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

P.S. My server is Suse Linux and I am not allowed to make any change in it. Only changes I can do are in my site or htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to figure out why your site is in Enterprise Mode. Here are the possibilities I know of, and their respective solutions:

- Whoever runs the domain your computer is on has set up an Enterprise Mode site list with your site included as requiring Enterprise Mode. To fix this, you'll need to contact that person and get them to exclude your site.
- You have chosen to load your page in Enterprise Mode by going to the tools menu and clicking "Enterprise Mode". This is good because it means the users of your site shouldn't be seeing the same issue. The fix is to hit that same menu option again on your site, and it should be taken out of Enterprise Mode.

Answer (score 1):

Try Using this in your code as IE 11 Enterprise mode emulates IE 8.

This will solve your design issues.

`<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks Gurdeep but this would render it as IE8 and I was really hoping I could find something which shows the site in all its glory in IE11. Still one-upping though.

Answer (score 0):

If your site is an intranet site, you can go to settings -> Compatibility View settings and then remove the check for "Display Intranet sites in Comparability View".

Or testing this with my site (I have been having a very similar issue), Make sure that your site is not on the compatibility view list on the same screen as the checkbox.

Comment: Unfortunately, I want this to automatically happen whenever anyone opens the site.

Answer (score 0):

To verify if your computer or user account are affected by Internet Explorer Enterprise mode, you will have to dig into the Registry.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\EnterpriseMode
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\EnterpriseMode
```

You might see two REG_SZ values here, `Enable` and `SiteList`.

If the above values exist, Enterprise Mode is enabled on your machine. The reverse is also true. If the above mentioned Registry keys do not exist, you are not affected by Enterprise Mode.

To see which sites are forced into Enterprise Mode, you can open the XML file that is the data value of `SiteList`. Now you can speak to your IT guys about getting the site list amended.

For more details about Enterprise mode, [here are the definitive articles](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/enterprise-mode-overview-for-ie11) from Microsoft.