# IE 11 Enterprise mode Aumatically gets on in our Application

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

We are using IE 11 for our Application

For some Pages Enterprise mode is disable and some pages it is Enable

Eg. On home page > disable
    After clicking on some Link of home Page>new Page will open > Here it is Enable

Any idea how automatically this Happens ?

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33108014/site-broken-ie11-in-windows-8-goes-to-enterprise-mode/), Enterprise Mode is controlled by GPO setting values in the Registry.

To verify if your computer or user account are affected by Internet Explorer Enterprise mode, you will have to dig into the Registry.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\EnterpriseMode
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\EnterpriseMode
```

You might see two REG_SZ values here, `Enable` and `SiteList`.

If the above values exist, Enterprise Mode is enabled on your machine. The reverse is also true. If the above mentioned Registry keys do not exist, you are not affected by Enterprise Mode.

To see which sites are forced into Enterprise Mode, you can open the XML file that is the data value of `SiteList`. Now you can speak to your IT guys about getting the site list amended.

For more details about Enterprise mode, [here are the definitive articles](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/enterprise-mode-overview-for-ie11) from Microsoft.